# How can I array_chunk mysqli results into chunks of 100 at a time

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way I can Array_chunk mysqli results, I am looping messages from a table and later pass the values into a method "Sms" The method will create a List of Sms objects which I pass through a function SendBatchSMS. my API end points can only allow 100 call per request.

I have tried array chunking the list into "$sms" which seams to work well when I print_r($sms), but when echo the response, it returns only 48/249 responses regardless of the size specified in the array_chunk function. My question is, is there a better option to achieve this, something like array_chunking the mysqli results instead of the array list?

```
$query_sch = "SELECT * FROM ct_queue";  
$sch_result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_sch);

$rows[] = mysqli_fetch_array($sch_result);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sch_result);
    
foreach($sch_result as $value)
{
    $phone = $value['phone'];
    $sender = $value['sender']; 
    $message = $value['message']; 
    $user_id = $value['user_id'];

    $link_id = NULL;
    $correlator = 'correlator_string';
    $endpoint = 'example.com';

    $token = "token_string";
    
    // $list = array();
    $version = "v1"; //DONT change unless you are using a different version
    $instance = new BonTech($token, $version);
    $list[] = new Sms($sender, $phone, $message, $correlator, null, $endpoint);
}
      
$row_chunks = array_chunk($list, 100);
      
foreach ($row_chunks as $chunk){
    $sms = array();

    ////////here we have 100 messages on each chunk
    ///////Loop through the messages in side the chunk
    foreach ($chunk as $row) {
        $sms[] = ($row);
    }
    // print_r($sms);
}

$response = call_user_func_array(array($instance, "sendBatchSMS"), $sms);
$response = json_encode($response, true);
$results = json_decode($response, true);
print_r($response);
```

Comment: Why are you calling `mysqli_fetch_array()` once before the `foreach` loop? `$rows` will contain the first row of results, the loop will process all the rest. So the loop skips the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `$sms` after the `foreach` loop is done. So it will only contain the last chunk. You need to use it inside the loop.

There's also no need to use a loop to copy `$chunk` to `$sms`.

You're also skipping the first row of results because of your call to `mysqli_fetch_array($sch_result)` before the first `foreach` loop.

`$instance` doesn't seem to be dependent on `$value`, so it shouldn't be in the `foreach` loop.

```
$query_sch = "SELECT * FROM ct_queue";  
$sch_result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query_sch);

$list = array();
foreach($sch_result as $value)
{
    $phone = $value['phone'];
    $sender = $value['sender']; 
    $message = $value['message']; 
    $user_id = $value['user_id'];

    $link_id = NULL;
    $correlator = 'correlator_string';
    $endpoint = 'example.com';

    $list[] = new Sms($sender, $phone, $message, $correlator, null, $endpoint);
}

$token = "token_string";
$version = "v1"; //DONT change unless you are using a different version
$instance = new BonTech($token, $version);
  
$row_chunks = array_chunk($list, 100);
      
foreach ($row_chunks as $sms){
    $response = call_user_func_array(array($instance, "sendBatchSMS"), $sms);
    print_r($response);
}
```

Comment: Let me try it out

Comment: This approaching seems to be looping through individual objects in the function instead of process the entire list of 100 at once thus the process is slow, when the number of sms objects is greater than100 it should not proces but it 's still processing,here the response {"status":false,"message":"A single Request can have batches of between 1 and 100!"}[{"status":false,"message":"Invalid Phone Number"},[{"status":false,"message":"Invalid Phone Number"}...] when the array_chunk is greater 100 it should display {"status":false,"message":"A single Request can have batches of between 1 and 100!"}

Comment: I can't see any way that could be happening.

Comment: Alright I don't know what the problem could be in the interation

Comment: I have noticed when the chunk size is more than 100 it will only send a request to the last chunk that is less than 100, but putting 100 as chunk value, seems to work well. Thank you

Comment: Since the API only allows batches up to 100, you shoiuldn't use a chunk size larger than that.

Comment: Yes, was just testing